# iframe not loading for application

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm having a problem with my app working on facebook. The app has been running for weeks/months with no problem. I last checked that it was running properly last Friday afternoon... This last Monday, the iframe for the app refuses to load. Weird thing about it, it seem to be intermittent. I can get it to load some of the time, but it was working just fine last friday.

The app is located here: https://www.facebook.com/idahopower?sk=app_130660760316387

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @offbysome And why do you think it should be? This is facebook.stackoverflow, not SO. Different FAQ. Have you read the blog "And because of that partnership, we are proud to announce that facebook.stackoverflow.com is launching today as the new official developer support channel for all Facebook developers." This is meant to be a developer support channel.

Comment: @user179700 Facebook.SO has the EXACT same rules as regular SO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103766/will-facebook-stackoverflow-have-its-own-moderators-to-clean-up-the-likely-flood/103768#103768

Comment: @offbysome As the blog says, "new official developer support channel for all Facebook developers." Have fun trying to convince people that questions about development are off-topic. This should have been a stackexchange site. I can't see FB thinking the standard SO approach is going to work as a "new official developer support channel for all Facebook developers."

Comment: @user179700 I agree about it being a new stackexchange site. I don't think Facebook and Stack Overflow are on the same page if you read both of their posts: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/ as Stack Overflow claims its just a filtered view (ie same rules)

Comment: @offbysome Agreed.The OP question seems fine as a ‘developer support’ question and off-topic as a SO question. I don’t see how this can work. Are FB Development CSS questions now on topic? Are there going to wind up being a half-dozen FB dev support SE forums? Facebook.programming, facebook.stackapps, facebook.webapps, facebook.ui, etcetera? This seems like one of those management thought it would be cool if..decisions.

Comment: @user179700: OffBySome is right. Facebook.SO has the same rules as the rest of Stack Overflow. If you disagree, feel free to make your case on [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally found the problem. It was an issue that was fixed by changing some settings in the developer panel of the app. We switched it to iFrame based landing page (It was already showing iFrame, but apparently there is another setting in the "advanced" section that enables the iFrame - weird)... Once again, this must have been a result of a Facebook update.

Answer (score 0):

What's your server error log say?
Are there any general problems with your hosting provider today?

Its most likely not a Facebook issue. Unless the proxy is having a bad day.

Comment: The weird thing is that the app will work if you go to: http://idahopowerpeople.com/facebook/landing_page.php or http://apps.facebook.com/poweringlives/

Comment: Thats a GET request. on the first link. Not sure why it would work on the second. Again its worth checking the server error log for enlightenment

Comment: It looks like the CDN is failing to deliver the content. Any workaround anyone know of?

Comment: I looked at the source code. Its incomplete HTML. That could be the problem. I see no opening html tags or a head or a body. The Facebook Proxy could just be rejecting your page. That would explain why the error message is in Blue.

Comment: maybe... I just added proper html structure to it to see if it makes a difference. So far it still isn't working.

Comment: Give it an hour and then run the Facebook linter on it http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. I ran it a sec ago and it gave me this error: 
Must namespace og:type You supplied the Open Graph type "other", which does not have a namespace. Either you misspelled a standard type, or you should add a namespace. Put 'xmlns:example="http://example.com/ns/#"' onto the <html> and then use <meta property="og:type" content="example:other" /> (but use your own site name and url).

Comment: You need the XMLNS entries: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ under getting started. Also Facebook tends to cache stuff for an hour, hence run the linter in an hour or so.